# Execute JSP files in IIS7 and Tomcat6

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, java, tomcat6, jsp

I want to execute JSP files in on Windows Server having `IIS7`, `Tomcat6` and `Java 1.6` installed.

Already Installed:

1. Java 1.6
2. IIS7
3. Tomcat6
4. BonCode Apache Tomcat AJP 1.3 Connector

Current scenario:
I am able to execute `JSP` files on the server if taken from `Tomcat` Example folder, if I create a custom `JSP` file it does not execute.

i.e.

1. www.somedomain.com/examples/jsp/jsp2/el/basic-arithmetic.jsp **[this works]**
2. www.somedomain.com/test.jsp **[this does not work]**

Can't figure out what exactly is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the solution by my own.

I simply choose to simply convert my Tomcat Server into web-server. Pointed my IP address to the Apache configuration file.